# RequestHandlerRetryAdvice with HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler not working

Tags: spring-integration, spring-retry

I have the below configuration file.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "application.properties" })
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableRetry
public class IntegrationBeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy(){
        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(5);
        return retryPolicy;
    }

    @Bean
    public FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy(){
        FixedBackOffPolicy p = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        p.setBackOffPeriod(1000);
        return p;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice(SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy, FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy){
        RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);
        retryAdvice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
        return retryAdvice;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="rtpRequestPostOperationRequestChannel")
    public MessageHandler httResponseMessageHandler(MessageChannel rtpRequestPostOperationResponseChannel, HeaderMapper<HttpHeaders> headerMapper, RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice) {
        List<Advice> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(retryAdvice);
        HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler("https://myhost:8080/rtp/request");
        handler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
        handler.setHeaderMapper(headerMapper);
        handler.setOutputChannel(rtpRequestPostOperationResponseChannel);
        handler.setExpectedResponseType(RtpResponse.class);
        handler.setAdviceChain(list);
        return handler;
    }

}
```

In my understanding, the retry would trigger if I make a request to a non-existing URL like

***https://myhost:8080/rtp/request123***

But the retry does not occur. Please advise if my understanding is incorrect or there is something wrong in the configuration.

Thanks

Comment: You're not injecting the `retryPolicy` into the template; but that would just mean it would use the default of 3 attempts. What do you mean by "does not occur"? Retries are typically silent. I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging to see the retry behavior.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Now I can see the retries being made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Gary's comment. The following configuration works

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "application.properties" })
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableRetry
public class IntegrationBeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy(){
        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(5);
        return retryPolicy;
    }

    @Bean
    public FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy(){
        FixedBackOffPolicy p = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        p.setBackOffPeriod(1000);
        return p;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice(SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy, FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy){
        RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        retryAdvice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
        return retryAdvice;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="rtpRequestPostOperationRequestChannel")
    public MessageHandler httResponseMessageHandler(MessageChannel rtpRequestPostOperationResponseChannel, HeaderMapper<HttpHeaders> headerMapper, RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice) {
        List<Advice> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(retryAdvice);
        HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler("https://myhost:8080/rtp/request");
        handler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
        handler.setHeaderMapper(headerMapper);
        handler.setOutputChannel(rtpRequestPostOperationResponseChannel);
        handler.setExpectedResponseType(RtpResponse.class);
        handler.setAdviceChain(list);
        return handler;
    }

}
```